# http://updatesite.rubypeople.org/release not a valid repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, plugins

I'm trying to get ruby on rails working through eclipse. 
I've been pointed to http://updatesite.rubypeople.org/release by several sites. 
But that location isn't up anymore.

Does anyone know where one could find the RDT.

Answer (score 3):

The RDT project (short for Ruby Development Tooling) is located at http://sourceforge.net/projects/rubyeclipse/. It seems a little bit outdated (last change 2 years, 3 months ago). I would not suspect it to work any more. I have used Aptana in the past (which worked well) and tried to use RDT and failed. Since 1,5 years, I use RubyMine (for bigger projects working all day in Rails) which works very well. But for doing just plain simple changes in Rails, I use VIM and this is sufficient most of the times.

Comment: I'm a big IDE lover.  The idea of a simple text editor for managing a project seems old.   I've done it heaps for c++, but once I got onto IDE's I have to say project management has become so much easier.

Comment: THat is true for me, too! But with Rails and Ruby, the things have gone different. I often open Vim to change something small, in the same time RubyMine would not even have started. And jts a great IDE!